# Canon ImageRUNNER 2530 printing problems

Tags: printing, canon

The Canon ImageRUNNER 2530 printer was working fine with Ubuntu Linux 17.04 but stopped working with Ubuntu 17.10. If there are any upgraded drivers or any applications should be installed to make it work, please help. The driver is Linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken. If there is an update, please let me know. The printer is being recognized but not printing.

Comment: Could you try re-installing!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Brightq driver available for linux and I would reccomend installing it https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/copiers-mfps-fax-machines/multifunction-copiers/imagerunner-2530?subtab=downloads-drivers

Comment: you will need to wait for Canon to have a look at 17.10 and issue a new driver: 3.4 was only issued in July; if only folks would stay with the LTS: long-term support; ie 16.04; others such as 17.10 should be viewed as experimental: keep clear unless you want to fix;